# Aggregate Sum on Django2

Tags: django, aggregate, django-queryset

I have 2 tables. Table A is

```
+--+------------------+ 
| ID |    Fastivalname    |
+--+------------------+ 
| 1   |    2020Xmas   |
+--+------------------+ 
| 2  |     2019Xmas    |
+--+------------------+ 
| 3 | 2020Thanksgiving |
+--+------------------+ 
| 4 | 2019Thanksgiving |
+--+—————————+
```

Fastival isForeignKey for table B,and table B is

```
+--+------------------+ ------------------+------------------+
| ID |    fastival_name_id    |        money   |        useofmoney    |
+--+------------------+ ------------------+------------------+
| 1   |        1         |     100        |              game
+--+------------------+ ------------------+------------------+
| 2  |         1        |      20         |              clothes
+--+------------------+ ------------------+------------------+
| 3 |          3        |    50           |              food
+--+------------------+ ------------------+------------------+
| 4 |         4         |      10         |              game
+--+------------------+ ------------------+—————————+
| 1   |         2       |      30         |              food
+--+------------------+ ------------------+------------------+
| 2  |         3        |      15         |              game
+--+------------------+ ------------------+—————————+
```

and models.py is:

```
class TableA(models.Model):
    Fastivalname = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class TableB(models.Model):
    fastival_name = models.ForeignKey(to=TableA, related_name="TableA_Fastival_name", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    money = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    useofmoney = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

Please someone tell me how to get the "sum of money in `game` of 2020xxx" in Django2?

I tried `context["money"] = TableB.objects.filter(fastival_id=TableA.objects.filter(Fastivalname__startswith=2020.values('id')[0]['id']).filter(useofmoney="game").aggregate(Sum('money'))['money']`. But that response "None"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single query on `TableB` and use the double-underscore syntax to perform joins/filters on related models/tables

```
TableB.objects.filter(
    fastival__Fastival__startswith='2020',
    useofmoney='game'
).aggregate(total=Sum('money'))['total']
```